# How do i edit the watermark for a DatePicker in WPF using Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, xaml, datepicker, expression-blend

I have created a simple Expression Blend 4 project with a DatePicker. I edited the template for the DatePicker, including its DatePickerTextBox, changing the watermark text from "Select a date" to "dd/mm/yyyy". The resulting XAML in Blend applies a style to the original DatePicker, and this style is stored as a resource in Window.Resources. However the editing done for the watermark text does not take effect. Any ideas? Thanks.
(Please note, i do not want to resort to code, i would like to understand how this can be achieved using Blend.). Here is the XAML for the window:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="HelloWorldBlen.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DatePickerStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTodayHighlighted" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectedDateFormat" Value="Short"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".5,0" StartPoint=".5,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_DisabledVisual"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBrush" Color="#A5FFFFFF"/>
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="DropDownButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="Pressed"/>
                                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF448DCA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#CCFFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF448DCA"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight">
                                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#EAFFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#C6FFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#6BFFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F4FFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <Grid Background="#11FFFFFF" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="18" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="23*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Border x:Name="Highlight" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="0,0,1,1" Margin="-1" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
                                            <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius=".5" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                                            <Border x:Name="BackgroundGradient" BorderBrush="#BF000000" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius=".5" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                                                <Border.Background>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Border.Background>
                                            </Border>
                                            <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1" StrokeThickness="1">
                                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.3,-1.1" StartPoint="0.46,1.6">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF4084BD"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFAFCFEA" Offset="1"/>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.48,-1" StartPoint="0.48,1.25">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF494949"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF9F9F9F" Offset="1"/>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Rectangle.Stroke>
                                            </Rectangle>
                                            <Path Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" Data="M11.426758,8.4305077 L11.749023,8.4305077 L11.749023,16.331387 L10.674805,16.331387 L10.674805,10.299648 L9.0742188,11.298672 L9.0742188,10.294277 C9.4788408,10.090176 9.9094238,9.8090878 10.365967,9.4510155 C10.82251,9.0929432 11.176106,8.7527733 11.426758,8.4305077 z M14.65086,8.4305077 L18.566387,8.4305077 L18.566387,9.3435936 L15.671368,9.3435936 L15.671368,11.255703 C15.936341,11.058764 16.27293,10.960293 16.681133,10.960293 C17.411602,10.960293 17.969301,11.178717 18.354229,11.615566 C18.739157,12.052416 18.931622,12.673672 18.931622,13.479336 C18.931622,15.452317 18.052553,16.438808 16.294415,16.438808 C15.560365,16.438808 14.951641,16.234707 14.468243,15.826504 L14.881817,14.929531 C15.368796,15.326992 15.837872,15.525723 16.289043,15.525723 C17.298809,15.525723 17.803692,14.895514 17.803692,13.635098 C17.803692,12.460618 17.305971,11.873379 16.310528,11.873379 C15.83071,11.873379 15.399232,12.079271 15.016094,12.491055 L14.65086,12.238613 z" Fill="#FF2F2F2F" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,3,4,3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            <Ellipse Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="3" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="3"/>
                                            <Border x:Name="DisabledVisual" BorderBrush="#B2FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="0,0,.5,.5" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Button x:Name="PART_Button" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,3,0" Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource DropDownButtonTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20"/>
                            <DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Style="{DynamicResource DatePickerTextBoxStyle1}"/>
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_DisabledVisual" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="1"/>
                                <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" Height="18" Margin="3,0,3,0" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="1" Width="19"/>
                                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}" StaysOpen="False"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="DatePickerTextBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WatermarkBrush" Color="#FFAAAAAA"/>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF99C1E2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF99C1E2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="watermark_decorator"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WatermarkStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unwatermarked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Watermarked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Watermark"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid x:Name="WatermarkContent" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <Border x:Name="ContentElement" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1"/>
                                <Border x:Name="watermark_decorator" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <ContentControl x:Name="PART_Watermark" Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Padding="2" Content="dd/mm/yyyy"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                <Border x:Name="FocusVisual" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" CornerRadius="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <DatePicker VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="250,112,272.36,0" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Style="{DynamicResource DatePickerStyle1}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit:

Fixed the issue described in your comment. This style modifies the `WaterMark's` `ControlTemplate` and works as expected.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DatePickerStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTodayHighlighted" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectedDateFormat" Value="Short"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".5,0" StartPoint=".5,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_DisabledVisual"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBrush" Color="#A5FFFFFF"/>
                                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DropDownButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="Pressed"/>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF448DCA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#CCFFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF448DCA"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight">
                                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#EAFFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#C6FFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#6BFFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F4FFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Grid Background="#11FFFFFF" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="18" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="23*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Border x:Name="Highlight" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="0,0,1,1" Margin="-1" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
                                                <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius=".5" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                                                <Border x:Name="BackgroundGradient" BorderBrush="#BF000000" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius=".5" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                                                    <Border.Background>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Border.Background>
                                                </Border>
                                                <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1" StrokeThickness="1">
                                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.3,-1.1" StartPoint="0.46,1.6">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF4084BD"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFAFCFEA" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.48,-1" StartPoint="0.48,1.25">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF494949"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF9F9F9F" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Rectangle.Stroke>
                                                </Rectangle>
                                                <Path Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" Data="M11.426758,8.4305077 L11.749023,8.4305077 L11.749023,16.331387 L10.674805,16.331387 L10.674805,10.299648 L9.0742188,11.298672 L9.0742188,10.294277 C9.4788408,10.090176 9.9094238,9.8090878 10.365967,9.4510155 C10.82251,9.0929432 11.176106,8.7527733 11.426758,8.4305077 z M14.65086,8.4305077 L18.566387,8.4305077 L18.566387,9.3435936 L15.671368,9.3435936 L15.671368,11.255703 C15.936341,11.058764 16.27293,10.960293 16.681133,10.960293 C17.411602,10.960293 17.969301,11.178717 18.354229,11.615566 C18.739157,12.052416 18.931622,12.673672 18.931622,13.479336 C18.931622,15.452317 18.052553,16.438808 16.294415,16.438808 C15.560365,16.438808 14.951641,16.234707 14.468243,15.826504 L14.881817,14.929531 C15.368796,15.326992 15.837872,15.525723 16.289043,15.525723 C17.298809,15.525723 17.803692,14.895514 17.803692,13.635098 C17.803692,12.460618 17.305971,11.873379 16.310528,11.873379 C15.83071,11.873379 15.399232,12.079271 15.016094,12.491055 L14.65086,12.238613 z" Fill="#FF2F2F2F" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,3,4,3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                <Ellipse Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="3" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="3"/>
                                                <Border x:Name="DisabledVisual" BorderBrush="#B2FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="0,0,.5,.5" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Grid.Resources>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Button x:Name="PART_Button" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,3,0" Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource DropDownButtonTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20"/>
                                <DatePickerTextBox  x:Name="PART_TextBox" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <DatePickerTextBox.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                                                        <Grid>
                                                            <Grid.Resources>
                                                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WatermarkBrush" Color="#FFAAAAAA"/>
                                                            </Grid.Resources>
                                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF99C1E2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"/>
                                                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF99C1E2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="watermark_decorator"/>
                                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                                    </VisualState>
                                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WatermarkStates">
                                                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unwatermarked"/>
                                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Watermarked">
                                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"/>
                                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Watermark"/>
                                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                                    </VisualState>
                                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>
                                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                                    </VisualState>
                                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                            <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                                                <Grid x:Name="WatermarkContent" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                                                    <Border x:Name="ContentElement" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1"/>
                                                                    <Border x:Name="watermark_decorator" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1">
                                                                        <ContentControl x:Name="PART_Watermark" Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Padding="2">
                                                                            <ContentControl.Template>
                                                                                <ControlTemplate>
                                                                                    <TextBlock Text="dd/mm/yyyy"/>
                                                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                                                            </ContentControl.Template>
                                                                        </ContentControl>                        
                                                                    </Border>
                                                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                                                    <Border x:Name="FocusVisual" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" CornerRadius="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                                                                </Grid>
                                                            </Border>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </DatePickerTextBox.Style>
                                </DatePickerTextBox>
                                <Grid x:Name="PART_DisabledVisual" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="1"/>
                                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" Height="18" Margin="3,0,3,0" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="1" Width="19"/>
                                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}" StaysOpen="False"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="PART_TextBox" Value="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource DatePickerStyle1}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I used Expression Blend 4 and then played around with the project in Visual Studio. Your style really does the trick! Thank-you.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately the style that you provided only changes the "Text" property of "PART_TextBox" and hence the text does not disappear once you start typing. It does not change the watermark.

Comment: @arlvin i'll look a bit more into in a few

Answer (score 6):

I came across this question and the answers when I needed to use a different watermark aswell. (In my case an empty watermark.) The code in the accepted answer was so long and complicated that I didn't really consider using it. The shorter answer by Jón Arnar works in some cases but in my case it doesn't. (The date picker is empty when the window is loaded. However as soon as I load a null value into a datepicker control the standard watermark appears again. This got me to take another look at the accepted answer and I shortened it so it just removes the watermark and nothing else (well...). For anyone searching like I was here is the shorter version with some explaination:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WatermarkBrush" Color="#FFAAAAAA"/>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF99C1E2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF99C1E2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="watermark_decorator"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WatermarkStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unwatermarked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Watermarked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Watermark"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid x:Name="WatermarkContent" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <Border x:Name="ContentElement" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1"/>
                                <Border x:Name="watermark_decorator" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <ContentControl x:Name="PART_Watermark" Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Padding="2">
                                        <ContentControl.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock Text=""/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </ContentControl.Template>
                                    </ContentControl>
                                </Border>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                <Border x:Name="FocusVisual" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" CornerRadius="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I personally use this in a user control but for a window `<Window.Resources>` would also work. This element is placed as child element directly after the opening tag of a `UserControl` or a `Window`. The key part is `<TextBlock Text=""/>`. Because I want an empty watermark, I specify an empty string.

This is the amount of code I was able to strip away. Is it possible to remove even more? Please comment if you know or edit this answer directly.

I hope this is helpful for the next person searching for the best solution.

Comment: Worked for me!  This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<DatePicker>
  <DatePicker.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
      <Setter Property="Text" Value="Watermark Text"/>
    </Style>
  </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

More information can be found on:
http://www.admindiaries.com/change-datepicker-watermark-in-wpf/

Comment: This removes the other styles that are set on the DatePickerTextBox, so you loose the Fore and Back colors and control template visual styles.

Comment: I noticed that when the text is changed and then deleted again (empty textbook, the original 'select date' appears again).

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void OnUserControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            setDateTimeWaterMark();
        }


private void setDateTimeWaterMark()
        {
            var dp = dpDob as DatePicker;
            if (dp == null) return;

            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dp) == 1)
            {
                var border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dp, 0);
                if (border == null) return;

                var grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0);
                if (grid == null) return;

                DatePickerTextBox txb = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(grid, 1) as DatePickerTextBox;
                if (txb == null) return;

                txb.Text = "MM/DD/YYYY";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do explain your answer rather than just putting in some code. It helps the OP, and it would improve your answer.