# Is there a way to change the text displayed in a DatePicker? Instead of "Select a date", show something else?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, xaml

I'd like to have the `DatePicker` prompt the user with a different message than "Select a date" for my `DatePicker`. Preferably I'd have a resx entry that would determine the value displayed, so is there a property of the `DatePicker` I can set to display a different opening message? I can deal with the resx portion of the problem myself, I just need help figuring out what property to set.

I've tried using `datepicker.Text = "Enter a date"`, just as a test, but it does not display the string.

Here is the xaml markup for the `DatePicker`:

```
<DatePicker Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="515,55.661,0,0" Name="dtpStartDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" FontSize="16" Background="White" SelectedDateFormat="Short" TabIndex="20"/>
```

Comment: thats not how you are supposed to use XAML. I higly suggest to learn using XAML and step away from the designer as soon as you can. it will make your life a lot easier in the future

Comment: You'll have to tell my supervisor because this isn't my code. I'm just working on it. How is this incorrect? It works perfectly to display everything needed.

Comment: it does not use the layout features provided by the laguage but instead uses hard defined margines. if you resize your application it will not work as expected by the user. By the way to achive your goal you will need to modify the orignal template for the datepicker refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712590/i-dont-want-message-select-date-in-datepicker

Comment: Imagine a car beeing driven backwards. You could argue "why is it bad to do it like this? it will get me everywhere it want it to!" and in fact you are correct but that still doesnt mean that using the car in the fashion it was designed to run will make your life a whole lot better and more comfortable and extent the lifetime of your car/software. So please tell your supervisor he is driving backwards

Comment: Oh ok, that's not a problem as they don't allow resizing for this application. I see what you're saying, and ideally we should be making a perfect app, but to be completely honest, this application isn't exactly top grade material, and isn't going to be. We just need it to do the bare minimum. Also, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an implicit `DatePickerTextBox` style where you hide the `ContentControl` named "PART_Watermark" and add a `TextBlock` with your custom text:

```
<DatePicker Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="515,55.661,0,0" Name="dtpStartDate"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" FontSize="16" Background="White" 
            SelectedDateFormat="Short" TabIndex="20">
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WatermarkBrush" Color="#FFAAAAAA"/>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF99C1E2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF99C1E2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="watermark_decorator"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WatermarkStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unwatermarked"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Watermarked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Watermark"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <Grid x:Name="WatermarkContent" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                    <Border x:Name="ContentElement" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="watermark_decorator" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <ContentControl x:Name="PART_Watermark" Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Padding="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="custom..." />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="FocusVisual" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" CornerRadius="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

To display the value of a resource that is defined in a `.resx` file, you can set the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` using the `x:Static` markup extension like this where "AppResources" is the name of the `.resx` file and "HelloWorld" is the name of the string resource in the file:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static local:AppResources.HelloWorld}" />
```

> The only problem is when I choose a date, the watermark stays and is overlaid by the date. Is there any way to fix this?

Good point. You could apply a `Style` to the `TextBlock` and use a `DataTrigger` to bind to the `SelectedDate` property of the `DatePicker`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static local:AppResources.HelloWorld}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DatePicker}}" 
                             Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: The only problem is when I choose a date, the watermark stays and is overlaid by the date. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @BrenCou: You could use a `Style` for the `TextBlock`. See my edit.

Comment: I actually found @BenjaminKrupp's answer very helpful at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394852/how-do-i-edit-the-watermark-for-a-datepicker-in-wpf-using-expression-blend. He updated the original to account for this problem. Thanks for the solution too though!